# Retrieve data/record from the database using dropdown list without reloading

Tags: php, ajax

```
<form method="post" action="a.php">
    <select name="taskOption">
    <?php
        include 'orderSelect.php';
        echo '<option>View Order</option>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
            <option value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'><?php echo $row[1]; echo " ";  
            echo $row[2]; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="click">
    </select>
</form>
```

I want to retrieve a record/ data from the database when I select something from the dropdown list. Any advice on what to look up or code for this to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in OP tag you should be using `ajax` Example with `JQuery` below:

```
$('select["name=taskOption"]').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.get('YOUR_FILE_WHICH_PROCCESS_RECORD.php',{selectVal:selected},function(data){
        console.log(data);//this is the value from your php file.
    })
})
```